# What is the better approach to insert data in Realm?

Tags: android, realm

I am using **Realm** as a database in my application for storing data locally. 
I am confused with the data insertion method in it. 
My question is that which one is better for inserting data in Realm **insert()**, **createObject()**, **copyToRealm()** and **copyToRealmOrUpdate()**.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have an integer as the primary key.

Then 0 is the default value for `int` fields, so if you have a RealmObject with 0 as the value then, it means that realm.createObject(YourRealmClass.class) will fail with the error mentioned below.

**RealmPrimaryKeyConstraintException**: Value already exists: 
as it will create an object with the default value.

What is the better way to create RealmObjects?

`copyToRealmOrUpdate()` or `insert()`. I will recommend you that use `copyToRealmOrUpdate()` because it is always better to use as it first checks if record exists. If record exists then it will update if record does not exits it will insert new record .

Comment: @neelkririt This is helpful for me. But looking for more eficeant answer.

Comment: I am happy it helped you.

Comment: I personally recommend `insertOrUpdate()`